# Confusion in understanding logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Suppose $y=u^v$ then $dy\over dx$$=v*u^{v-1}=$$dy\over dx$$1\over y$$=logu^v$

Does this means that the power which $e$ will be raised so that it is equal to $u^v$ would be equal to $u^v$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you trying to do. But in order to find the derivative write
$$
u^v = e^{v \log u}
$$
and then take the derivative.

The other way (equivalent to the first one) is to take the logarithm
$$
\log y = v \log u
$$
and then differentiate
$$
\frac{y^{'}}{y} = (v \log u)^{'} \implies y^{'} = y \cdot (v \log u)^{'}.
$$

Comment: Can you explain how the second way is equivalent to the first one?

Comment: Well, in both methods you are doing literally the same thing: differentiation of $v \log u$ and, not surprisingly they lead to the same result. They are equivalent in this sense. I think you should try some simple examples to feel that they are actually the same. For instance, take $u(x) = v(x) = x$ and try to follow both ways. Of course, the results must coinside :)

Answer (score 0):

$$y=u^v\iff \log y=v\log u$$ so that

$$(\log y)'=\frac{y'}y=v'\log u+v\frac{u'}{u}$$

and

$$y'=\left(v'\log u+v\frac{u'}{u}\right)u^v.$$